# Add data-src tag for image insertion

Tags: typo3, typoscript, src, fluid

I'm configuring a LazyLoad JS on a Typo3 website and i want to add the data-src tag to insert image. Currently I use only src :

```
<f:if condition="{mediaElement.type} == 0">
    <f:media file="{mediaElement}" class="img-responsive lazy-image" title="{mediaElement.originalResource.title}" alt="{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}" data="{src: '{mediaElement}'}"  width="{f:if(condition: settings.list.media.image.width, then: settings.list.media.image.width, else: settings.media.width)}" height="{f:if(condition: settings.list.media.image.height, then: settings.list.media.image.height, else: settings.media.height)}"/>
</f:if>
```

I tried to add this code for the code above :

```
 data="{src: '{f:media file="{mediaElement}'}"
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `f:media` viewhelper returns a full image (or video) tag.

what you need is only the URL. so you might use an `uri.*` viewhelper.
If you use more than images it could get complicated as there is no pendant to `media`

Comment: I added   `data="{src: '{f:uri.image(image: {mediaElement})}'}"`  to the code, but the HTML output does not work and it displays that `<img data-src="{f:uri.image(image: {mediaElement})}" class="img-responsive" src="image.jpg" width="300" height="180" alt="">`

Comment: Maybe it w orks without apostrophees? `data="{src: {f:uri.image(image: {mediaElement})}}"`. Just a guess...